# Group adjacent nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to group adjacent nodes **<speech>** with a following-sibling **<attrib>** with **<disp-quote>**. Below is the sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<sec id="s1">
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <para>Sample text here</para>
    <sec id="s1.1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <para>Blah blah blah</para>
        <speech>
            <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
            <para>sample speech</para>
        </speech>
        <speech>
            <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
            <para>sample speech</para>
        </speech>
        <speech>
            <speaker>JOEL</speaker>
            <para>sample reply</para>
        </speech>
        <attrib>From eternity...</attrib>
        <para>Blah blah blah 2</para>
        <speech>
            <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
            <para>sample speech</para>
        </speech>
        <test>zzzz</test>
        <speech>
            <speaker>JOEL</speaker>
            <para>sample reply</para>
        </speech>
        <para>Blah blah blah 3</para>
    </sec>
    <sec id="sec1.22">
        <title>aaa</title>
        <para>Text</para>
        <speech><speaker>Facilitator:</speaker><para>Have you been in <bold>love</bold>?</para></speech>
        <speech><speaker>Interviewer:</speaker><para>Yes <italic>I</italic> have been</para></speech>
        <speech><speaker>Facilitator:</speaker><para>Honesto, yung totoo?</para></speech>
        <attrib>Information source</attrib>
    </sec>
</body>
```

If I use the following template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


<!-- XSLT Template to copy anything, priority="-1" -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//sec">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
            group-adjacent="self::speech or (self::attrib and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::speech])">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[2]">
                    <disp-quote>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </disp-quote>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nothing happens. The stylesheet did not group the **speech** and **attrib** nodes. I think this is because of the nested **<sec>** elements. I have removed

```
<sec id="s1">
<title>Introduction</title>
<para>Sample text here</para>
```

and the end tag

```
</sec>
```

And it produced the correct results. The correct output should be (with nesting of **<sec>**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<sec id="s1">
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <para>Sample text here</para>
    <sec id="s1.1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <para>Blah blah blah</para>
        <disp-quote>
            <speech>
                <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
                <para>sample speech</para>
            </speech>
            <speech>
                <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
                <para>sample speech</para>
            </speech>
            <speech>
                <speaker>JOEL</speaker>
                <para>sample reply</para>
            </speech>
            <attrib>From eternity...</attrib>
        </disp-quote>
        <para>Blah blah blah 2</para>
        <speech>
            <speaker>PHRYNIA</speaker>
            <para>sample speech</para>
        </speech>
        <test>zzzz</test>
        <speech>
            <speaker>JOEL</speaker>
            <para>sample reply</para>
        </speech>
        <para>Blah blah blah 3</para>
    </sec>
    <sec id="sec1.22">
        <title>aaa</title>
        <para>Text</para>
        <disp-quote>
            <speech>
                <speaker>Facilitator:</speaker>
                <para>Have you been in <bold>love</bold>?</para>
            </speech>
            <speech>
                <speaker>Interviewer:</speaker>
                <para>Yes <italic>I</italic> have been</para>
            </speech>
            <speech>
                <speaker>Facilitator:</speaker>
                <para>Honesto, yung totoo?</para>
            </speech>
            <attrib>Information source</attrib>
        </disp-quote>
    </sec>
</body>
```

The idea here is to group adjacent **speech** nodes with a following sibling **attrib** in **<disp-quote>** tag and leave the rest as is.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well which result do you want with nested `sec` elements? Post a sample input and the result you want for that that input.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited my post to reflect the input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the two `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>` use `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`.

Comment: I'm laughing at myself now and will slap my face later. I never saw this simple fix due to pressure. Thanks for your help.